# obtener tipo de dato de una columna en mysql

Tags: mysql, tipos

En Oracle SQL puedes hacer esto

```
PROCEDURE PRO_ADD_ALUMNO(
    pNombre IN ALUMNO.NOMBRE%TYPE,
    pEdad IN ALUMNO.EDAD%TYPE,
);
```

¿Cómo sería el equivalente, si es que hay, en MySQL?

Comment: Solo es saber el tipo de dato?

Comment: en teoría sí, es para el caso especifico que comento en la descripción, quiero en los parámetros de los procedures no poner el tipo de dato como int o varchar si no obtener el tipo de dato de una columna

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con algo así:

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='database'
  AND TABLE_NAME='tabla'
  AND COLUMN_NAME='campo';
```

Si no proyectas ningún campo, dejando `SELECT *`, verás mucha más información.

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)